# Playstore Server

Tags: android, server, save, google-play

So like, I want the highscores to be saved online but I am guessing that I'll need a server for that. If I did upload a game on Play store, will they provide us servers to save scores online for the other users to see others' highscore? Maybe I still have to do something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for Google Play Game Services (https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards) which provides a standard implementation for leader-boards across android.

The android specific implementation information can be found at this link: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/leaderboards

Submitting scores to your leader boards (which you setup on the Google Play Developer console website) is as simple as calling  `Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mGoogleApiClient, LEADERBOARD_ID, {score});`

Showing leader boards is also very simple and is a few lines of code which you will find explanations and examples for at the second link I provided.

Comment: Oh I see. And by using that code, the other players can see others' score?

Comment: If you follow the guides at the links, then yes :)